# How to clean up this directory traversal?

Tags: python, directory

I have the following directory structure that i want to traverse and call a function on each (loaded) file if the directories and file pass certain criteria

```
self.directories[0]   
│
└───maps_dir_1
│   │   file1.json
│   │   file2.txt
│   │   file3.json
│   └───subfolder1
│       │   file111.txt
│       │   file112.txt
│       │   ..
│   
└───maps_dir_1
│   │   file4.json
│   │   file5.txt
│   │   file6.json
```

I have a working way but it is super nested and ugly and i am sure there has to be a cleaner way, but i am unsure what it is.

```
for maps_dir in self.directories:
    for map_dir in os.listdir(maps_dir):
        if fails_check1(map_dir):
            continue
        for filename in os.listdir(os.path.join(maps_dir, map_dir)):
            if not filename.endswith(".json"):
                continue
            file_path = os.path.join(map_dir, filename)
            if os.path.isfile(file_path):
                with open(file_path, encoding="utf-8") as demo_json:
                    demo_data: Game = json.load(demo_json)
                match_id = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]
                if fails_check2(match_id):
                    continue
                self.do_stuff(demo_data, match_id)
```

Comment: suggest you look into using `pathlib.Path` and generators in order to simplify the code. `Path` has useful higher level abstractions than the `os.path` methods, and generators can reduce visual/conceptual nesting of loops.

Comment: Also, ```for file_path in glob.glob(os.path.join(maps_dir, '*', '*.json')): ``` after ```for maps_dir in self.directories:``` would shorten the traversal significantly.

Comment: Maybe use `os.path.walk()`?

Comment: @CaptainCaveman i think that would skip this step `if fails_check1(map_dir)` right?

Comment: @Kache i guess i could extract the nested loops into generator expressions. That would definitely reduce the indentation. Although i am not sure if it makes it more readable. But maybe it will, ill have a look.

Comment: @Barmar i dont think this will help me here. The main use of that is to go recursively through a directory tree, right? But i know exactly the level i want to go to,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example. I use:

- `pathlib.Path` - for its better abstractions
- generators - to reduce nesting and break up the iteration into conceptual parts

```py
import json
from pathlib import Path

directories = ['some/list', 'of/directories']

# generator function
def map_dirs():
    for path in directories:
        for map_dir in Path(path).iterdir():
            if check1(map_dir):
                yield map_dir

# generator expression alternative, if you don't mind the long line
json_files = (file for map_dir in map_dirs() for file in map_dir.glob('*.json') if check2(file.stem))

# conceptually flattented into a single loop
for json_file in json_files:
    with open(json_file) as demo_json:
        demo_data = json.load(demo_json)
        do_stuff(demo_data, json_file.stem)
```

I use the boolean-flipped `check1()` and `check2()` b/c expressing in the positive reads more naturally IMO (and it's shorter).

Comment: I effectively went with your solution now.

Although i did add back the negatives because i want to log messages when they fail.